# How can I hold down a Key using the keybd_event in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard

I'm currently trying to develop an App that enables the user to send Keystrokes to a specific program. I already can send keys and hold down specific keys like that:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]        
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0); //Start holding the key down
keybd_event(key, 0, KEY_UP_EVENT, 0); //Stop holding the key down
```

Holding Shift down while sending letters capitalizes them already.
But if I'm holding down a letter (and send it to notepad for example), then just writes that letter once. If I do the same with my physical keyboard, it starts writing the letter until I let go again. Does anyone have a tip or clue how I can manage that?

I already experimented with the stopwatch, but that wasn't working either.

Comment: Physical keyboards have a feature called "typematic" which autorepeats characters which are held down. You'll have to emulate that too. More generally, you probably should be using the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace for programmatically controlling other applications.

Comment: @RaymondChen That means the physical keyboard is just sending the key again and again until I lift the key? If that's the point, I guess sending the keystroke multiple times should work too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RaymondChen , this question has been answered.

> Physical keyboards have a feature called "typematic" which autorepeats characters which are held down. You'll have to emulate that too.

If you want to simulate the repetition of a keystroke, just send multiple KeyDown and KeyUP-Events.

Comment: I'm not convinced that that is sufficient. If you look at the information available from the [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) message you'll see, among others, the repeat count. Do repeated calls of `keybd_event` cause this counter to go up on each `WM_KEYDOWN` message?

Comment: @IInspectable AFAIK, the repeat count on `WM_KEY[DOWN|UP]` is always 1, since it is the message that is generated when the key is initially pressed down and finally released.  It is the generated `WM_CHAR` messages in between them that have an increasing repeat count while the key is held down, since those are the messages that get auto-repeated.