# Simulating button hold doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, winapi, keyboard

```c
#include <windows.h>
#define VK_W 0x57

int main()
{
    keybd_event(VK_W, 0, 0, 0); // Press down the key
    Sleep(3000);
    keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Release the key
}
```

This code is supposed to hold down a key for 3 seconds, and upon further checking through https://drakeirving.github.io/MultiKeyDisplay/ it does hold it for 3 second, but the default behaviour isn't present. The default behaviour I want is for it to repeatedly send the key when I hold it down (like what happens when I hold it down physically). This doesn't happen here, because when I open Notepad, it doesn't repeat the key.

I even tried simulating scancodes to see if it has an effect, but to no avail.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#define VK_W 0x57

int main()
{
    keybd_event(0,
                 MapVirtualKey(VK_W, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC),
                 KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | 0,
                 0);
    Sleep(3000);
    keybd_event(0,
                 MapVirtualKey(VK_W, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC),
                 KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
                 0);
}
```

How do I simulate holding the key so that it behaves the same way as when I hold it down physically?

Comment: This is for C#, but the same answer applies here too, since it is the same API: [How can I hold down a Key using the keybd_event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262420/). In short, you have to simulate the repeat behavior yourself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you know how I can find out the time for a keyboard in which I have to hold before it starts repeating the message and the delay between each message?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no public API to get that info. The timing of physical key events is managed by the individual keyboard controller/driver.